# React-native does not find Genymotion

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I installed android studio, I configured the environment variables and everything, I installed genymotion and created a device, but running the `react-native run-android` in the project folder occurs the following error:

```
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

please help me in this problem. React-native does not find Genymotion disositivo, in this link has more details: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382115/react-native-n%C3%A3o-reconhece-genymotion

Answer (score 1):

It tries to connect the emulator to the **ADB**, by the **IP** of the device. To check the IP of the device, simply click on an emulator window, the IP address is in the title of the window.

No terminal will run the command:

```
$ adb connect ip_of_your_emulator:5555
```

Soon after, run:

```
$ adb devices
```

If the name of your file appears in the list, your emulator has been connected successfully!

With the emulator open, simply run the native `run-android` in the folder of your project.

Comment: NewProject>adb devices

List of devices attached

192.168.142.103:5555  device

NewProject>adb connect 192.168.142.103:5555

already connected to 192.168.142.103:5555

NewProject>adb devices

List of devices attached

192.168.142.103:5555 device

NewProject>react-native run-android

error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem earlier this month. As far as I can tell the newer versions of Genymotion don't register on `adb devices`, a [user in the Expo forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/impossible-to-run-expo-with-genymotion/4600/12) speculates it's because they have a paywall now.

I recommend switching to Android Studio, that's what I did to solve my problem.

Comment: I was using avd of android studio, however it is very poorly optimized, it leaves my notebook very heavy, I have 6GB of RAM, but it is still unfeasible.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's the only solution. Fingers crossed someone comes with a better answer than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I ran `react-native`  with the `--verbose` flag, and got the following error:

```
...
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development 
environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
...
```

So, I gave permissions to the `android/gradlew` folder as follows:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

But then, I got an error regarding Google Play Licenses:

```
error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android SDK 
licenses using Android SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses".
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

So yeah, pretty the solution was:

- Downloading Android Studio with its own SDK
- Change the env variabe `ANDROID_HOME` to the one installed with Android Studio
- Installing Google Play Licensing Library (In Android Studio, go to Settings>SDK Manager>SDK Tools, select *Google Play License Library* and then install)